# search for points within a polygon, postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to find a coordinate in a polygon coordinate, but can not get it to work. How should I?

Points coordinate in table "location" column "latlon":

A: 60.2653608 -3.6923519

B: 60.241668 -3.652401

```
SELECT latlon, st_contains(latlon, ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((60.237949  -3.654019,
60.240247 -3.661016,
60.243500 -3.658463,
60.240127 -3.642761,
60.240127 -3.642761)))', 4326))  FROM location
```

Comment: What do you mean with "can not get it to work". Add to the question what do you expect, what do you get instead and the error message. By the way: where are your coordinates supposed to be? They are probably wrong, since they are in the middle of a ocean: https://www.google.de/maps/place/3%C2%B041'32.5%22S+60%C2%B015'55.3%22E/@-3.7434136,59.7880263,9.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-3.6923519!4d60.2653608

Comment: I know, the coordinates are examples. What I want you to show me the coordinates that are within the polygon coordinate

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Contains.html) says:

> boolean ST_Contains(geometry geomA, geometry geomB);
>
> St_Contains Returns TRUE if geometry B is completely inside geometry A

Also, you must reverse the order of the arguments: FIRST the polygon, THEN the point

Comment: I just saw, I'm doing as I indicas.

`
SELECT id FROM zones
WHERE ST_Contains(zones.geometry, 
    ST_Transform(
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(60.2653608 -3.6923519)', 4326), 4326
    )
) 
`

But I jump the following error:
ERROR: function st_contains(character varying, geometry) does not exist

Comment: 1) The function St_Contains() want 2 `geometry` arguments. The column zones.geometry is of type `character varying`, but need to be `geometry`. 2) Try reading the documentation an do a tutorial online: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0  and http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro

Comment: thank you very much for helping me, I've been able to solve